# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for multiple rows, not columns

Tags: php, mysql

I need a query that will insert multiple records into a table but if exists, update the column labeled status for each row.

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the solution to this problem but what if I have more than one row? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is only updating 1 of 2 rows.

For example, I want to insert table A into table B which works fine but if there's an update to the status column on table A, i want to update the status column for each row on table B.

Table A

| tableA_id | tableA_company_entity. | tableA_product | tableA_ordern | tableA_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple_44 | Phone | 456 | Pending |
| 2 | Apple_44 | Watch | 689 | Pending |

I tried the following query:

```
 INSERT tableB (
 tableB_company_entity,
 tableB_product,
 tableB_ordern,
 tableB_status
 )
 SELECT
 tableA_company_entity,
 tableA_product,
 tableA_ordern,
 tableA_status
 FROM tableA
 WHERE
 tableA_company_entity = '$tableA_company_entity'
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 tableB_status = VALUES(tableB_status)
```

Like i said, the insert runs fine but if the status changes and i run the query again to initiate the update, it does an insert instead of updating and creates duplicate records like the following:

Table B

| tableB_id | tableB_company_entity. | tableB_product | tableB_ordern | tableB_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple_44 | Phone | 456 | Pending |
| 2 | Apple_44 | Watch | 689 | Pending |
| 3 | Apple_44 | Phone | 456 | Pending |
| 4 | Apple_44 | Watch | 689 | Pending |

If i make tableB_company_entity a unique ID before insert using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE tableB
ADD CONSTRAINT u_cnst UNIQUE (tableB_company_entity);
```

The insert only saves 1 row like the following:

Table B

| tableB_id | tableB_company_entity. | tableB_product | tableB_ordern | tableB_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple_44 | Phone | 456 | Pending |

My desired outcome is to insert both rows and if there's an update, to update the status on both rows.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can't have multiple rows with the same unique key. Unique means only one row with that value.

Comment: is there another way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Use a SELECT query to test if any rows exist. If they do, use `UPDATE`, otherwise use `INSERT`.

Comment: What if i need to update and insert at the same time?

Comment: You can use a transaction to make all the queries update the DB atomically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What about the REPLACE statement?

Comment: It also needs a unique key; the difference is that it deletes and inserts instead of updating. You can't get around it -- the only way for MySQL to tell automatically if a row should update or insert is by matching the new contents against a unique index.